# Using PHPUnit global installation with Silex' WebTestCase

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, functional-testing, silex

I have global composer's `autoload.php` and local project's `autoload.php`. PHPUnit, when running uses global one, and bootstrap project's.
I decided to use `Silex\WebTestCase` (it is the project dependency, not global) that uses `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` (which is global) with other `Silex` classes (which again, in the project).

So, I got spahgetti dependencies, and when I run this functional test, I've got error **PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client' not found in /var/www/vhosts/app.ilimnet.dev/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Client.php on line 32**, and found in stack trace, that it tries to use global autoloading, which ofcourse hasn't this packages.

Is there the way to resolve this awkward dependencies with 2 autoloaders?

Comment: You might be missing "symfony/browser-kit" package. Try running "composer update symfony/browser-kit" and repeat.

Comment: Stupid me. That is the actiual problem. Thank you